# Connecting my domain to my Firebase hosted app

Tags: firebase, dns, firebase-hosting

This is probably a simple question, but I'm in a bit of a rush to try and get the domain linked tonight, or at least as soon as possible. I want to make sure that I've done the correct thing and waiting is indeed all that needs to be done.

On the Firebase website, I went to 'connect my domain' and added the supplied TXT record onto my GoDaddy hosted domain.

I saw some other posts about the 'Host' field needing to be something other than my domain which I'm trying to link, which is what Firebase told me to set it as. Is this something I should change?

Currently I just changed the TXT records and I assume I have to wait for the record to propagate before it will be able to verify my domain, as of now it says I need to check my settings again.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I seems that you've solved your issue, or? If it's the case then you can also answer your problem yourself, see below.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted a solution on behalf of the question author)*.

After a few hours it still hadn't connected, I changed the domain/host on the host I bought the domain from to '@' instead of what Firebase supplied me and it verified shortly afterwards.